# Python run script after other script is finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, process.start

I have three python scripts: `schedule.py`, `script1.py` and `script2.py`.

I want to start running `script1.py` and `script2.py` by `schedule.py`. Moreover, I want to run `script1.py` first, and then activate `script2.py` after `script1.py` has finished.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25107089/7326714), but I think this person wants to do this via Terminal, or a similar program. I want to do this via Python.

For the moment, I have,

```
import script1.py
import script2.py
```

How do I go about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend wrapping your python scripts (script1.py, script2.py) within their own functions and then calling those functions in order from the schedule.py

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the code you have in these scripts by invoking

```
script1.whatever_function_you_have
```

Just treat them like modules. No different than importing os, sys, or any other module you create. If you want to run the entire py script, then you can always create a main loop at the bottom of the file to run the code. For example:

```
import script1
import script2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    script1.foobar()
    script2.goobat()
```

This would be placed at the bottom of the schedule file and you list what code you want to run and it will run it.

Comment: Just did a quick google search and found this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603482/execute-multiple-python-files-using-a-single-main you might want to look a little harder next time when researching for your answers as you will invoke plenty of downvotes for lack of trying. Just a helpful tip.